# How to append all elements of one list to another one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Probably a simple question but I would like to parse the elements of one list individually to another. For example:

```
a=[5, 'str1'] 
b=[8, 'str2', a]
```

Currently

```
b=[8, 'str2', [5, 'str1']]
```

However I would like to be `b=[8, 'str2', 5, 'str1']`

and doing `b=[8, 'str2', *a]` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use addition:

```
>>> a=[5, 'str1']
>>> b=[8, 'str2'] + a
>>> b
[8, 'str2', 5, 'str1']
```

Comment: This is definitely the nicest option. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Use `extend()`

```
b.extend(a)
[8, 'str2', 5, 'str1']
```

Answer (score 15):

The efficient way to do this is with extend() method of list class. It takes an iteratable as an argument and appends its elements into the list.

```
b.extend(a)
```

Other approach which creates a new list in the memory is using + operator.

```
b = b + a
```

Comment: This is definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a
[5, 'str1']
>>> b=[8, 'str2'] + a
>>> b
[8, 'str2', 5, 'str1']
>>>
```

for **extend()** you need to define **b and a** individually...

then `b.extend(a)` will work

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to unpack a list inside another list at an arbitrary position:

```
>>> a=[5, 'str1'] 
>>> b=[8, 'str2'] 
>>> b[2:2] = a   # inserts and unpacks `a` at position 2 (the end of b)
>>> b
[8, 'str2', 5, 'str1']
```

Similarly you could also insert it at another position:

```
>>> a=[5, 'str1'] 
>>> b=[8, 'str2'] 
>>> b[1:1] = a
>>> b
[8, 5, 'str1', 'str2']
```